# print random string from string with multiply words

Tags: php

I am new to php and trying out some different things.
I got a problem with printing a random value from a string from multiply values.

```
    $list = "the weather is beautiful tonight".
    $random = one random value from $list, for example "beautiful" or "is"
```

Is there any simple way to get this done? 
Thanks!

Comment: the function you want is [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// First, split the string on spaces to get individual words
$arg = explode(' ',"the weather is beautiful tonight");

// Shuffle the order of the words
shuffle($arg);

// Display the first word of the shuffled array
print $arg[0];
```

Comment: he would learn more if you diffident just proved the whole answer

Comment: If i where him:i have tested the code, see it worked, then i take a look at all function at php.net or elsewhere, because i want too learn.  "Is there any simple way to get this done?" Was the question and i have an answer. I dont have asked: Can you teach me too archive that?

Answer (score 1):

well, as @Dagon suggested, you can use explode() to get an array of strings, then you can use rand($min, $max) to get an integer between 0 and the length of your array - 1. and then read the string value inside your array at the randomly generated number position.

Comment: Dagon maybe will tell you taht you have missed to explain how to get the length of the array;)